# Flash AS3: URLLoader data to video playback

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, video-streaming, preloader

Without getting into the details of why (its for school) I'm trying to use a custom preloader I've created to load a Flash video.

I've created the animations, and the loader functions, but on the `Event.COMPLETE` event, how do I pass the data I've loaded into `myUrlLoader` to an `FLVPlayback` component?

Or should I even be using the `FLVPlayback` component? Everything up till:

```
myUrlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,
function(e:Event){
    //what do I do?
});
```

...seems to be fine. Any suggestions?

PS: Gotta submit this soon. Would set bounty if I could.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, I would write a video player using the NetStream, NetConnection, and Video classes, but you could try to do it this way:

I would put your preloader on top of the FLV playback component, and use the functions you set up to add and remove it from the stage as appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response **John**; I sort of have that set up right now, I removed it from the example. It simply hides the preloader `MovieClip`, which contains all the junk for the animations, etc., revealing the `FLVPlayback` component underneath. I just wanna pass the data I've got loaded off to something to be played though. Mucking with how it's loading it right now is probably not a good option as I'm hovering around the 20 minute mark until it needs to be submitted.

I really hope I haven't gone about this in a way that needs to be revamped...